# Trying to print a table uisng PDO

Tags: php, pdo

New to PDO and I have a PDO connection script which I am requiring at the top but this is what I have to try and just display the database that is made of up 4 employees and their birthdays. Whenever I run it, I get nothing. Am I at least in the right ballpark here?

```
<?php

require "pdoconnect.php";

try{
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT bid, bname, bday FROM birthday"); 
$stmt->execute();
# setting the fetch mode   
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
if( ! $result){
    print('No Records Found');
} 
else{  
    echo "<table border='1' align='center' cellpadding='5px' cellspacing='2px'>";
    //while($row = $stmt->fetch()) 
    echo "<tr><th>Bid</th><th>Name</th><th>Birthdaay</th><th colspan='2'></th></tr>";
        foreach($result as $row){
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>";
            echo $row['bid'];
            echo "</td>";

            echo "<td>";
            echo $row['bname'];
            echo "</td>";

            echo "<td>";
            echo $row['bday'];
            echo "</td>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
    }
}
catch(PDOException $e){
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: `foreach($result as $row)` change it like  `foreach($row as $result)`

Comment: What do you mean by get nothing?

Comment: I'm using a software called Kahuna, because it's required, and unlike the local host I usually use it doesn't display any errors even though I have a .htaccess in  directory that these scripts are in. I'm not that familiar with Kahuna yet. All it displays is the HTML employee drop down selection box that I haven't connected to this yet.

Comment: Do a `var_dump` of `$result` right after the fetchall and verify that it contains what you think it should.

Comment: That would be wrong @OmerTekbiyik